# STORED PROC - select then insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm new in coding stored procedures. Basically I would just like to transfer top 10 records of table 1 to table 2(which I created). My code can't insert the records I selected from table 1. I'm not sure if I'm missing something or I'm doing it wrong. Please help. Thanks in advance!

Note:

1.) Table 1 and Table 2 are with the same datatypes.

2.) I need parameters for each column for me to be able to call them in my c#.net graph

Here's my SP:

**

> ```
> USE [GDW]
> GO
> SET ANSI_NULLS ON
> GO
> SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
> GO
> ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_BI_Get_AsiaTopTen]
>
> AS BEGIN
>   DECLARE 
>   @fyname nvarchar(120),
>   @fmonth nvarchar(120),
>   @fmonth_num int = null,
>   @world_area nvarchar(120) = null
>
>     SELECT TOP 10 
>   @fyname= [FYName], 
>   @fmonth= [FMONTH], 
>   @fmonth_num= [FMONTH_NUM],
>   @world_area= [World_AREA]
>   FROM [dbo].[tbl_BI_FastReport1_Temp]
>   WHERE [World_AREA] = 'Asia'
>   AND [FMONTH_NUM] = '201401'
>
>   INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_BI_AsiaTopTen]
>   (
>   [FYName],
>   [FMONTH],
>   [FMONTH_NUM],
>   [World_AREA]
>   )
>   VALUES
>   (
>   @fyname,
>   @fmonth,
>   @fmonth_num,
>   @world_area
>   )
>
>   END
> ```

**

Comment: When you use `top` you probably want to use an `order by` clause too, as the rows returned will be arbitrary without `order by`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_BI_Get_AsiaTopTen]
AS 
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

      INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_BI_AsiaTopTen]
                      ([FYName],[FMONTH],[FMONTH_NUM],[World_AREA])
    SELECT TOP 10 [FYName] 
                , [FMONTH] 
                , [FMONTH_NUM]
                , [World_AREA]
    FROM [dbo].[tbl_BI_FastReport1_Temp]
    WHERE [World_AREA] = 'Asia'
    AND [FMONTH_NUM] = '201401'
 -- ORDER BY SomeCOlumn 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this instead:

```
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_BI_AsiaTopTen]
    (
    [FYName],
    [FMONTH],
    [FMONTH_NUM],
    [World_AREA]
    )
    SELECT TOP 10 
    [FYName], 
    [FMONTH], 
    [FMONTH_NUM],
    [World_AREA]
    FROM [dbo].[tbl_BI_FastReport1_Temp]
    WHERE [World_AREA] = 'Asia'
    AND [FMONTH_NUM] = '201401'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need stored procedure for this...  As I remember, you can do

insert into table2 Select top 10 col1, col2, col3 from table1 where col1= ....

checkout this msdn link...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx